# App is crashing after using DatePicker in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-context

I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't get those solutions to work for my fragment. I think there is some issue with the context which I am unable to solve. Kindly look in to the code to help me understand the problem. Thanks!

I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't get those solutions to work for my fragment. I think there is some issue with the context which I am unable to solve. Kindly look in to the code to help me understand the problem. Thanks!(Repeated the text because it was asking for more details which were not required)

From logcat:

```
 2020-05-14 07:14:13.100 31145-31145/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-05-14 07:14:13.103 31145-31145/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-05-14 07:14:13.120 31145-31145/? E/o.android.imoi: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-05-14 07:14:13.143 30730-30730/fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp E/AnimationUtils: RuntimeException for unknown animation name, resouce ID #0x10a0026
2020-05-14 07:14:13.144 30730-30730/fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp E/AnimationUtils: loadAnimation: getConfiguration = {1.0 410mcc4mnc [en_GB,fr_FR,es_ES] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h668dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2076) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=standard} s.59 mkbd/h desktop/dshowBtnShape = 0  themeSeq=0 0 0  ?dc}
2020-05-14 07:14:13.144 30730-30730/fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp E/AnimationUtils: loadAnimation: getDisplayMetrics = DisplayMetrics{density=3.0, width=1080, height=2076, scaledDensity=3.0, xdpi=422.0302, ydpi=423.96976}
2020-05-14 07:14:13.144 30730-30730/fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp E/AnimationUtils: loadAnimation: resourceName = android:anim/date_picker_fade_in_material
2020-05-14 07:14:13.150 30730-30730/fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp, PID: 30730
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.DatePicker
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:119)
        at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:109)
        at fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp.ui.calendar.CalendarFragment.showDatePickerDialog(CalendarFragment.java:140)
        at fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp.ui.calendar.CalendarFragment$4.onDateSelected(CalendarFragment.java:117)
        at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.dispatchOnDateSelected(MaterialCalendarView.java:1357)
        at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.onDateClicked(MaterialCalendarView.java:1432)
        at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.onDateClicked(MaterialCalendarView.java:1474)
        at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.CalendarPagerView.onClick(CalendarPagerView.java:206)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14177)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.DialogViewAnimator
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.DialogViewAnimator
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:113)
        at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:203)
        at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:176)
        at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:148)
2020-05-14 07:14:13.153 30730-30730/fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:144)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:119)
        at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:109)
        at fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp.ui.calendar.CalendarFragment.showDatePickerDialog(CalendarFragment.java:140)
        at fr.loveyourchakra.menstruallunarcyclesapp.ui.calendar.CalendarFragment$4.onDateSelected(CalendarFragment.java:117)
        at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.dispatchOnDateSelected(MaterialCalendarView.java:1357)
        at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.onDateClicked(MaterialCalendarView.java:1432)
        at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.onDateClicked(MaterialCalendarView.java:1474)
        at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.CalendarPagerView.onClick(CalendarPagerView.java:206)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14177)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ab_solid_dark_holo.9.png"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:133)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:383)
        at android.view.animation.Animation.<init>(Animation.java:256)
        at android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation.<init>(AlphaAnimation.java:40)
        at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:204)
        at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:179)
        at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:143)
        at android.widget.ViewAnimator.setInAnimation(ViewAnimator.java:314)
        at android.widget.ViewAnimator.<init>(ViewAnimator.java:58)
        at com.android.internal.widget.DialogViewAnimator.<init>(DialogViewAnimator.java:38)
            ... 46 more
```

My Fragment

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    private CalendarViewModel calendarViewModel;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        calendarViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CalendarViewModel.class);

        final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);




        calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
                calendarView.clearSelection();
                for(CalendarDay calendarDay:DateUtils.calendarDaysGenerater(pastList)){
                    if (calendarDay.equals(date)) {
                        //Scrolling Date picker DialogBox
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        showDatePickerDialog(calendarDay,widget.getContext());

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;

            }
        };


        return root;
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(CalendarDay calendarDay,Context context){
        int day = calendarDay.getDay();
        int month = calendarDay.getMonth();
        int year = calendarDay.getYear();
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                context,
                android.R.style.Widget_Holo_ActionBar_Solid,
                mDateSetListener,
                year,month,day);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace; that whole section of red lines around the three you have here.

Comment: Yes added the whole log

Comment: you've an error at `Binary XML file line #18` in your xml layout

Comment: This would seem to be the cause: `android.R.style.Widget_Holo_ActionBar_Solid`. That argument would need to be a theme ID, but that's actually style ID. Any particular reason you're trying to use that? There's a constructor without that parameter, so you can just remove that argument, if you don't really need it.

Comment: @Zain if that were the case, it wouldn't run before I added the datepicker but it was working fine

Comment: @MikeM. It Worked! Thank you!